# XenServer External Storage

Tags: command-line-interface, citrix, xen

I have a XenServer with a few VMs on it. I'm trying to copy some of the VMs on it and pass them onto another XenServer host.

From what I've read the steps to do this follows like this. 
Create the SR(probe, plug)
Forget the SR(probe, unplug)
Introduce the SR to other host(probe, pdb create, plug, introduce )

Are these steps in the right order? Also, what param values should I use for the "xe sr-create" for the param type and content-type?

I will be using an external drive attached to a "clamp" using USB 3.0 from the drive to 2.0 to the machine.

Thanks :D

Comment: i'm thinking xe sr-create name-label"XX" content-type=ext type=udev device-config:device=/dev/sdc  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can export them directly, you don't need to do all the storage stuff if you don't want to.

If you are able to shut down the vms the steps are:
Shut down vm in xencenter
Export vm to share
Import vm in xencenter (other xenserver)
Change mac address of nics for imported vm to match the original vm
Boot up and confirm it works
Delete original vm

If you are not able to shut down the vms the steps are:
Make snapshot of vm
Create vm from snapshot
Then all the steps above, using the new vm as the 'original'

The export will not send empty space, so if your vm is 250GB but only 10GB used, it will send 10GB.

Answer (score 0):

You have below 2 safest options

1. export and import of VM wherever you want
2. Do a cross pool migration of the VMs